# Linker error with Qt Signal/Slot example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, linker-errors

I have a Qt application with multiple classes that use signals and slots and it compiles just fine. However, when I make a custom class inside the main CPP (main.cpp) file, I get a linker error.

Here is the code I use:

```
class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Counter() { m_value = 0; }

    int value() const { return m_value; }

public slots:
    void setValue(int value)
    {
     if(value!=m_value)
     {
         m_value = value;
         qDebug() << "Value " << value;
         emit valueChanged(value);
     }
    }

signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);

private:
    int m_value;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    Counter a, b;
    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

    a.setValue(12);     // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 12
    b.setValue(48);     // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 48

    QTimer::singleShot(0, &app, SLOT(quit()));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall Counter::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@Counter@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)  
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall Counter::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@Counter@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall Counter::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@Counter@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)   
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall Counter::valueChanged(int)" (?valueChanged@Counter@@IAEXH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Counter::setValue(int)" (?setValue@Counter@@QAEXH@Z)
```

**This linker error does not occur when I place the counter in a separate header file. What's the reason for this behavior?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with `qmake`.

The `moc` is made to run on header files automatically by default, because that's where classes are declared in general. Notice that this rule is defined in the makefile, you can manually run `moc` on a source file.

You have to inform `qmake` that the file contains a class. To do this, put `#include "filename.moc"` after the declaration of `Counter`. You can see more details [here (QtCentre)](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28580-Why-does-qmake-moc-only-process-header-files) or [here (doc)](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/moc.html#writing-make-rules-for-invoking).

If you're working with another tool than `qmake`, say CMake, you have to specify a rule to force the moc to parse the `.cpp` files (the simplest is to process them all). For files that do not contain a Qt object class, `moc` will generate an empty file.

However, even if this class is made to be 'private', I advise you to declare it in a header (for example `counter_private.h`). For example, Qt source is using this trick.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have only one code file. If you use the default way to create a Qt project build (qmake && make or QtCreator), the MOC only scans *.h files. If you have all your code in one main.cpp the MOC will not create any code, but that's needed for Signal/Slots to work.

The simplest way to make this specific example working would be adding a line "#include "main.moc"" at the end of your main.cpp. This dependency will be detected by qmake and the needed Makefile targets will be created.

The cutest way would be the clean one: One class - One header and one implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

They moc/uic custom build commands are done on the header file, so it compiles when put in a seperate header/source file and not when put in the same source file